# Custom Selector not refreshing when placed in Grid

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom Selector created using PXCustomSelectorAttribute class, I am not able to do AutoRefresh as this option is not available. Can anyone tell me how to Autorefresh the custom selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example how to create a CustomSelector and set it to AutoRefresh mode.

```
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace TestLib
{
    public class SOOrderExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
    {
        #region UsrTestField
        [PXDBString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "TestField")]
        [CustomerPriceClass()]
        public virtual string UsrTestField { get; set; }

        public abstract class usrTestField:IBqlField {  }
        #endregion
    }

    public class CustomerPriceClassAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
    {
        public CustomerPriceClassAttribute()
        : base(typeof(ARPriceClass.priceClassID))
        {
            this.DescriptionField = typeof(ARPriceClass.description);
        }
        protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
        {
            ARPriceClass epc = new ARPriceClass();
            epc.PriceClassID = ARPriceClass.EmptyPriceClass;
            epc.Description = PX.Objects.AR.Messages.BasePriceClassDescription;
            yield return epc;
            foreach (ARPriceClass pc in PXSelect<ARPriceClass>.
            Select(this._Graph))
            {
                yield return pc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this you need to add the field to the UI from Layout Editor and set the AutoRefresh property in the Ext Properties section to True. See the screen-shot below.

[image]

UPDATE:

In case of Grid you need to add you will need to add Control in the Levels of the Grid like is shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

After adding the control you will see the Field Editor (3) for that field.

In the properties of the Field Editor the AutoRefresh is available and you can set it to True:

[image]

Comment: I have done in similar way but after adding the control to grid. I am not seeing Auto Refresh property. in the above screen shot it is in the form but my requirement is to add it to grid.

Comment: @PrathyushaMelapindi I have updated my answer for the case of grid